# jQuery manipulation within multiple elements

Tags: jquery, loops

I have multiple sections... within these sections there are few child elements... I need to manipulate so that for each of the section move 1 element e.g. .inner after another element e.g. h1

my attempt is here http://jsfiddle.net/shavindra/LDpwq/1/ but the problem is it's not looping through and print good at the end.. but I want the output to be different as shown below...

Initial state:

```
<section class="greeting">
  <h2>Greetings 1</h2>
  <div class="time">Morning</div>
  <div class="inner">Good 1</div>
</section>

<br />
<br />

<section class="greeting">
  <h2>Greetings 1</h2>
  <div class="time">Afternoon</div>
  <div class="inner">Good 2</div>
</section>

<br />
<br />

<section class="greeting">
  <h2>Greetings 1</h2>
  <div class="time">night</div>
  <div class="inner">Good 3</div>
</section>
```

After manipulation

```
<section class="greeting">
  <h2>Greetings 1</h2>
  <div class="inner">Good 1</div>
  <div class="time">Morning</div>
</section>

<br />
<br />

<section class="greeting">
  <h2>Greetings 1</h2>
  <div class="inner">Good 2</div>
  <div class="time">Afternoon</div>
</section>

<br />
<br />

<section class="greeting">
  <h2>Greetings 1</h2>
  <div class="inner">Good 3</div>
  <div class="time">night</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You should accept an answer, if one solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was two problems with your original code:

```
$(".greeting").each(function() {
    $(this).children('.time').addClass("on");
    $(this).children('.time').after($('.inner'));
});
```

**1)** you're selecting all the elements with `inner` class to move after:

```
$('.inner')
```

Intead, use only the one in the current div:

```
$(this).children('.inner')
```

**2)** You´re using the `after` function, whichs inserts the content passed as parameter *after* the element on which you call the function. On the other hand `insertAfter` operates in the inverse way. From [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

> With .after(), the selector expression preceding the method is the
>   container after which the content is inserted. With .insertAfter(), on
>   the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector
>   expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted after
>   the target container.

So you can change your code to this:

```
$(".greeting").each(function() {
    $(this).children('.time').addClass("on");
    $(this).children('.time').insertAfter($(this).children('.inner'));
});
```

or this:

```
$(".greeting").each(function() {
    $(this).children('.time').addClass("on");
    $(this).children('.inner').after($(this).children('.time'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".time").each(function() {
    $(this).before($(this).siblings('.inner'));
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LDpwq/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".greeting").each(function() {
    $(this).children('div:eq(0)').before($(this).children('div:eq(1)'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LDpwq/15/